# Wrapping multiple server calls using IEnumerable and IEnumerator

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, wcf, listbox

I am binding result of a WCF call (list of items) to a WPF listbox. Each item has a corresponding image which should be obtained and displayed in listbox using a separate server call. I wanted to make sure Listbox is virtualized and call to get images are not fired unless a particular item is in display port. How about using IEnumerable and IEnumerator so that I can write code to bring image for each item in MoveNext(). Does this approach guarantee that images are lazy loaded? What are other best patterns to acheive this?

Comment: You would usually have a view model class for the list items. That class would have an `Image` property of type `ImageSource` which would be the source of a binding on the `Source` property of an Image control in the ItemTemplate of the ListBox. The view model property would lazily load the image.

Comment: Adding to what @Clemens said - remember to lazy load in the background then raise a property change to avoid locking the UI whilst hitting the service.